# One Entity Framework Model for Multiple Database Providers

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have used Entity Framework to generate models for database before. The thing is that Entity Framework generate the model for a specific provider (SQL Server, Oracle, etc ..). How can I generate a model that may work with many providers.

I thought about handcrafting my own Data Access Layer using the `DbProviderFactory` class. But building the model from scratch involves a lot of work this is why I was wondering if I could generate an Entity Framework Model which works with more than one provider?!!!

Comment: Did you solved this problem? If yes, maybe you can share it.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. So, I went with writing my own DAL which was limited to the providers I have included at the time.

Comment: Did you try the Stackoverflow Dapper and its Extensions. Dapper is a lightweight ORM which is fast and simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ONE DbContext and target multiple database providers!

> How can I generate a model that may work with many providers.

Entity Framework will generate provider-specific SQL for you.  The real problem you have to solve is how to tell EF what provider to use when you have to make provider-specific calls on your own i.e. call provider-specific stored procs etc.  You also have to deal with the issue of provider-specific migrations, database initializers, and provider-specific integration testing.

You can use [AdaptiveClient](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient) and [AdaptiveClient.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient.EntityFramework) for all the challenges above.

In fewest words, AdaptiveClient allows you key your connection strings to provider-specific and transport-specific components in your application.

When a specific connection string is selected (i.e. MSSQL or MySQL) AdaptiveClient uses Autofac to resolve the correct components for you.

All you need to do is register your provider/transport specific components using keys that you define.  AdaptiveClient provides a registration helper that makes this a very simple process since it provides methods that are specific to Entity Framework components.

- Use SOLID design principals to construct your service layer
- Create a service layer that is scalable and loosely coupled
- Create services that are granular and testable
- Create provider-specific migrations
- Create provider-specific database initializers
- Easily drop-and-recreate your database for integration testing
- Easily inject a single client that provides access to your entire service layer
- Use a service manifest (facade) to call any service from within any other service

Download the complete working [Zamagon Demo](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient.EntityFramework.Zamagon).  The demo illustrates migrations, database initializers, drop-and-recreate scenarios for integration testing and every bullet point in the list above.

[AdaptiveClient is available as a nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveClient/).

[AdaptiveClient.EntityFrameworkCore is also available as a nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveClient.EntityFrameworkCore/).